# fill column with values in another columns based on their conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to fill a column (KE) with values in other columns (K2007/K2008/K2009) based on the conditions (Year). For examle, If "Year" is 2007, KE would be 1.

```
Year <- c(2007,2008,2009)
K2007 <- c(1,2,3)
K2008 <- c(4,5,6)
K2009 <- c(7,8,9)
KE <- c(1,5,9)
```

Thanks in advance,

---2022/06/24 update----
I'm so sorry that the data have another limit.
I want to assign values to KE conditional on two column values in addition to "year."

```
Year <- c(2007,2008,2009)
X <- c(10, 20, 30)
Y <- c(40, 50, 60)
    K2007 <- c(1,2,3)
    K2008 <- c(4,5,6)
    K2009 <- c(7,8,9)
    KE <- c(1,5,9)
```

In this case, when Year = 2007, X = 10 and Y = 40, KE will be 1.

---

I successfully got the results below the code.

```
test <- ddd %>%
  mutate(KE = case_when(
       Year == 2007 ~ ke_2007,
       Year == 2008 ~ ke_2008,
       Year == 2009 ~ ke_2009,
       TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

Thanks,

Comment: just for understanding, as an example, in what condition will KE = 7?

Comment: I would like to remove such a case. The column KE would depend on Year.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to keep the original columns you could pivot the data to a tidier long format, remove the "K" from the original column names, and only keep rows in which Year is the same as the old column:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat |>
  pivot_longer(K2007:K2009, values_to = "KE") |> 
  mutate(name = sub('.', '', name) |> as.double()) |> 
  filter(Year == name) |> 
  select(-name)
```

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    Year    KE
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2007     1
#> 2  2008     5
#> 3  2009     9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df <- data.frame(K2007 , K2008 , K2009)

KE <- sapply(seq_along(Year) , 
       \(x) df[ x,grep(Year[x] , names(df))])

KE

#[1] 1 5 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(
  year = c(2007,2008,2009),
  k2007 = c(1,2,3),
  k2008 = c(4,5,6),
  k2009 = c(7,8,9))
    
tbl %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year, values_to = 'ke') %>% 
  filter(name == str_c('k', year)) %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  left_join(tbl, ., 'year')
    
# A tibble: 3 x 5
   year k2007 k2008 k2009    ke
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2007     1     4     7     1
2  2008     2     5     8     5
3  2009     3     6     9     9
```